# Is it ever possible to build on Ruins?

Tags: endless-legend

I'm fairly new to Endless Legend, and one thing keeps throwing off all my plans.  After I search a Ruin (of any sort) and the glow goes away, I forget it's there and try to build my city/districts and the Ruins keep getting in the way!  After they stop serving a game purpose (that I'm aware of), is there a way to knock them down or otherwise build in those hexes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accroding to the devs, no, [it's not possible](http://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/613936039630469895/).

But some factions get bonuses on ruins and there is a technology that allows you to search ruins a second time.